Find hierarchy of Reporting persons using python
I have a data frame which have three columns User Name, Designation, and Vertical Report. User Name has a designation and to whom the username report is in Vertical Report column.
DATASET


USERNAME              DESIGNATION CODE    VERTICAL REPORT
RAJKUMAR.MALVIYA           BM              GOURAV.MOD
GOURAV.MOD                 ASM             PRASANNA.NAIK
PRASANNA.NAIK              RSM             MILIND.DESHMUKH
SANJAY.BHATNAGAR           NSM             ARUN
UMANG.GOHIL1               BM              HIREN.JASANI
MILIND.DESHMUKH            ZSM             SANJAY.BHATNAGAR 
HIREN.JASANI               ASM             BHAVIN.GANDHI
SACHIN.PAWAR               NSM             ARUN
BHAVIN.GANDHI              DSM             ANURAG.JOSHI
ANURAG.JOSHI               ZSM             SACHIN.PAWAR
SACHIN.PAWAR               NSM             ARUN
SANGRAM.KEDARI             BM              NIKHIL.BELKHEDE
NIKHIL.BELKHEDE            DSM             SACHIN.PAWAR 
SACHIN.PAWAR               NSM             ARUN


This is my data set In which First user RAJKUMAR.MALVIYA had Designation Code BM and his Vertical Report person is GOURAV.MOD similarly GOURAV.MOD has designation ASM and his Vertical Report person is PRASANNA.NAIK AND so on. this makes a hierarchy of usernames and vertical report based on their designation and I want to get solved this hierarchy in python. And if their is missing any Designation it should be filled with L plus COLUMNNUMBER number.
SOURCE CODE

`# Initialize designation dictionary
designations = ['BM', 'ASM', 'CSM', 'DSM', 'RSM', 'ZSM', 'NSM']
designation_dict = {designation: [] for designation in designations}

# Iterate through each row in the Data Frame
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    username = row['User Name']
    designation = row['Designation Code']
    vertical = row['Vertical Report']



for _, row in df.iterrows():
    username = row['User Name']
    designation = row['Designation Code']
    vertical = row['Vertical Report']

    # Check if the designation is not 'DST'
    if designation.strip() and designation != 'DST':
        # Append username to the appropriate designation list
        designation_dict[designation].append(username)

        # Find the row corresponding to the vertical report
        search row = df[df['User Name'] == vertical]

        # If a match is found, update username, designation, and vertical
        if not search_row.empty:
            username = search_row.iloc[0]['User Name']
            print(username)
            designation = search_row.iloc[0]['Designation Code']
            print(designation)
            vertical = search_row.iloc[0]['Vertical Report']
            print(vertical)

# Fill any remaining blank cells with 'BLANK'
max_length = max(len(lst) for lst in designation_dict.values())
for key in designation_dict:
    while len(designation_dict[key]) < max_length:
        designation_dict[key].append('BLANK')

# Create DataFrame from the designation dictionary
output_df = pd.DataFrame(designation_dict)
`



EXPECTED OUTPUT DATAFRAME

BM                ASM           CSM   DSM             RSM           ZSM               NSM
RAJKUMAR.MALVIYA  GOURAV.MOD     L3   L4              PRASANNA.NAIK MILIND.DESHMUK SANJAY.BHATNAG 
UMANG.GOHIL1      HIREN.JASANI   L3   BHAVIN.GANDHI   L5            ANURAG.JOSHI   SACHIN.PAWAR
SANGRAM.KEDARI    L2             L3   NIKHIL.BELKHEDE L5            L6             SACHIN.PAWAR


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for your answer. This code works for the given sample data but when I run this code on the actual data. code returns all BM in the BM column But In ASM Column all the names of ASM Inserted which does not belongs to the reporting person to previous BSM. Every new designation name should belongs to previous.

I hope you are well and that it helps you.
How does it work?

Groups usernames by designation and converts them to lists, creating a new DataFrame called df_designation.
Initializes a new empty DataFrame called df_vertical.
Iterates over each designation in the designations list and assigns the corresponding usernames to each column of the df_vertical DataFrame.
Use the explode method to expand the lists of usernames into separate rows and then reset the indexes.
Replaces the NaN values ​​in the df_vertical DataFrame with strings formatted as f'L{n}', where n is the column number.
Prints the resulting DataFrame.

'
# Import the pandas library
import pandas as pd

# Create the original dataframe
data = {
    'USERNAME': ['RAJKUMAR.MALVIYA', 'GOURAV.MOD', 'PRASANNA.NAIK', 
                 'SANJAY.BHATNAGAR', 'UMANG.GOHIL1', 'MILIND.DESHMUKH', 
                 'HIREN.JASANI', 'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'BHAVIN.GANDHI', 
                 'ANURAG.JOSHI', 'SANGRAM.KEDARI', 'NIKHIL.BELKHEDE', 
                 'SACHIN.PAWAR'],
    'DESIGNATION': ['BM', 'ASM', 'RSM', 'NSM', 'BM', 'ZSM', 'ASM', 'NSM', 
                    'DSM', 'ZSM', 'BM', 'DSM', 'NSM'],
    'VERTICAL REPORT': ['GOURAV.MOD', 'PRASANNA.NAIK', 'MILIND.DESHMUKH', 
                        'ARUN', 'HIREN.JASANI', 'SANJAY.BHATNAGAR', 
                        'BHAVIN.GANDHI', 'ARUN', 'ANURAG.JOSHI', 
                        'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'NIKHIL.BELKHEDE', 
                        'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'ARUN']
}

# List of designations
designations = ['BM', 'ASM', 'CSM', 'DSM', 'RSM', 'ZSM', 'NSM']

# Create the original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_vertical = pd.DataFrame()

# Group usernames by designation
df_designation = df.groupby(
    'DESIGNATION')['USERNAME'].apply(list).reset_index()

# Assign usernames to each column
for des in designations:
    # Use explode to expand lists into separate rows and reset index
    df_vertical[
        des] = df_designation.loc[
            df_designation[
                'DESIGNATION'] == des, 'USERNAME'].explode().reset_index(drop=True)

# Replace NaN with f'L{n}' where n is the column number
for col in df_vertical.columns:
    # Get the column number
    n = df_vertical.columns.get_loc(col) + 1  
    
    # Fill NaN values with f'L{n}'
    df_vertical[col] = df_vertical[col].fillna(f'L{n}')

# Print the result
print(df_vertical)

'

Logic

Using pandas indexing we can filter out target data subset for each designation, .loc[] is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array.

Here for each designation row length is not same to make it equal first we find max number of row among all columns using this operation


max([len(i) for i in dict_.values()])

Based of our current columns length we can create extra new fillers.

max([len(i) for i in dict_.values()]) - len(dict_[designation]))
Solution
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'USERNAME': ['RAJKUMAR.MALVIYA', 'GOURAV.MOD', 'PRASANNA.NAIK', 'SANJAY.BHATNAGAR', 'UMANG.GOHIL1', 'MILIND.DESHMUKH', 'HIREN.JASANI', 'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'BHAVIN.GANDHI', 'ANURAG.JOSHI', 'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'SANGRAM.KEDARI', 'NIKHIL.BELKHEDE', 'SACHIN.PAWAR'],
        'DESIGNATION CODE': ['BM', 'ASM', 'RSM', 'NSM', 'BM', 'ZSM', 'ASM', 'NSM', 'DSM', 'ZSM', 'NSM', 'BM', 'DSM', 'NSM'],
        'VERTICAL REPORT': ['GOURAV.MOD', 'PRASANNA.NAIK', 'MILIND.DESHMUKH', 'ARUN', 'HIREN.JASANI', 'SANJAY.BHATNAGAR', 'BHAVIN.GANDHI', 'ARUN', 'ANURAG.JOSHI', 'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'ARUN', 'NIKHIL.BELKHEDE', 'SACHIN.PAWAR', 'ARUN']
    }
)

designations = ['BM', 'ASM', 'CSM', 'DSM', 'RSM', 'ZSM', 'NSM']
dict_ = {}

for designation in designations:
    dict_[designation] = list(set(data.loc[data['DESIGNATION CODE'] == designation]['USERNAME'].tolist()))

for index, designation in enumerate(designations):
    dict_[designation].extend([f'L{index+1}']*(max([len(i) for i in dict_.values()]) - len(dict_[designation])))

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

Output
                 BM           ASM CSM              DSM            RSM              ZSM               NSM
0  RAJKUMAR.MALVIYA    GOURAV.MOD  L3  NIKHIL.BELKHEDE  PRASANNA.NAIK     ANURAG.JOSHI  SANJAY.BHATNAGAR
1      UMANG.GOHIL1  HIREN.JASANI  L3    BHAVIN.GANDHI             L5  MILIND.DESHMUKH      SACHIN.PAWAR
2    SANGRAM.KEDARI            L2  L3               L4             L5               L6                L7

